# Do I have this Use Case diagram correct?

Tags: uml

With this Use Case diagram, I'm unsure if I'm currently doing it correctly or not. Checked online and each site is giving me a different answer. I just need a direction or someone to correct me.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting as I am currently going through the exact same discussion with a client...

I would say "no" simply because I am unsure of what this actually represents.
A use case must bring a benefit to a user, and I really don't this in this diagram. What does Actor0 actually trying to accomplish? I do not get this from the diagram.

Did you write down statements before trying to do this? I find that going to a whiteboard and writing down what your actor's goal and how you see this happening so that the actor achieves the goal is a good start to better understanding the use case and differentiate the system being built from external systems. One way to do this is through a set of user stories (or use case slices).

And answering Thomas Kilian's excellent questions will also help you in this task!

Also, you are doing something that I see too often from people starting with use cases (and sometimes with UML experience): use case decomposition as a set of actions - basically trying to model a set of activities by breaking it down. Doing that is typically the second step in your analysis (e.g., by using activity and sequence diagrams).

Answer (score 0):

No. Only "Register" (what?) and "Add/View Details" (which?) can be regarded as use cases since they add value. Neither "Login" nor "Main Menu" are use cases. The first is a constraint and the second an implementation detail.